# jQuery - Sortable with divs

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible to sort div layers? Examples only show list items being sorted.

I currently use one function to control dynamically created divs (based on a MySQL result). This one function keeps the movable layers in one div.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the portlets demo, all works fine.

Comment: could u give demo or sample code

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery UI [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) plugin should do what you want.  The example uses divs, but it should work on any type of DOM element.

Comment: I found the answer just, thank, so 1+